# Steam client API to add non-steam games?

Tags: automation, steam

I wanted to automate adding some non-steam games to my library on Steam Deck, similar to how EmuDeck can automatically add things to your library, but I was having a hard time finding how this works. Is there like a steam client API I can use? Or is there a different way of doing this by editing some file steam reads from to get the non-steam games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out there is https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD.

Others finding this might also want to check out https://github.com/berenm/steam-cli for a nicer cli interface, and https://github.com/sonic2kk/steamtinkerlaunch/wiki/Add-Non-Steam-Game for more functionality.